# Activator run single test from Suite of tests

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, typesafe-activator

Hi all in my play project i have created a suite of tests.

```
class AcceptanceSuite extends Suites(new SomeTest, new SomeTest2, new SomeTest3) with OneAppPerSuite
```

Is there a way to specify the Suite to run a single test? Right now if I want to run one of the tests I have to comment out whatever tests i don't want. This is the command I run to run the suite.

```
activator "test-only acceptance.AcceptanceSuite"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
testOnly acceptance.SomeTest
```